# sql statements and pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There is a pdo wrapper class that has turns off emulation or prepared statements using:

```
setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

I am seeing where some of the sql statements are written using standard non parameterized methods such as seen below:

```
select * from table where name = '".$name."'.
```

Are these kind of statements protected against sql injections even though a pdo wrapper is employed?

Comment: No. How do you expect PDO to provide protection when it doesn't know which part of that statement is supposed to be "protected" ?

Comment: Relevant read: [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism)

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of protecting from injections is quite wrong.

It is not PDO just by it's presence (which can be interfered by some wrapper) protects your queries, but **prepared statements**.

As long as you are using prepared statements, your queries are safe, no matter if it's PDO or wrapper, or even poor old mysql ext.

But if you are putting your data in the query directly, like in your example, there is **no protection at all**